# How can i find next smallest Element Key by Value in Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like this:

```js
times = {
   "dawn": "Mon Jul 06 2020 01:34:46 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)",
   "dusk": "Mon Jul 06 2020 22:43:02 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)",
   "evening": "Mon Jul 06 2020 19:06:36 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)",
   "morning": "Mon Jul 06 2020 08:02:55 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)"
};
```

I want to compare the current time with this object and want to **get the key as return value, which is closest to the current time.**

I try to use this function, but I never get the right key back.

```js
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
    return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value || object[key] < value);
}

let date = new Date();
getKeyByValue(times, date);
```

What do I have to change for this to work?

Comment: You are comparing strings, not dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You're comparing strings, not dates. Use `Date.parse()` to get a number, or `new Date()` to get a Date object.
2. You're only looking for the first matching value with `.find()`, not the closest. You'll have to use a more custom solution to find the closest.

---

This will find the time before the given time which is closest:

```js
// Just so this example works in the future, while still
// comparing against the current time:
const makeTime = (h, m) => {
  const today = new Date();
  return new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), h, m);
}

const times = {
  "dawn": makeTime(05, 00),           //  5:00am
  "morning": makeTime(07, 00),        //  7:00am
  "afternoon": makeTime(12, 00),      // 12:00pm
  "late afternoon": makeTime(17, 00), //  5:00pm
  "dusk": makeTime(19, 00),           //  7:00pm
  "evening": makeTime(20, 00),        //  8:00pm
  "night": makeTime(23, 00)           // 11:00pm
};

// The important part is here:
const closestTime = Object.entries(times)
  .map(([k, v]) => [ k, Date.now() - Date.parse(v) ])
  .reduce((pre, cur) => cur[1] < pre[1] && cur[1] > 0 ? cur : pre)[0];

console.log(`Right now, it is ${closestTime}.`);
```

Here's how it works:

```
// Get a list of [ key, value ] lists for every key and value in `times`.
const closestTime = Object.entries(times)

// Turn that list of [ key, value ] and turn it into a list of keys and
// the differences between compareTime and the date in the value. Values
// in the future create negative numbers, since their Unix Epoch 
// representation is larger than the compared time.
// IE: [ [ 'morning', 12300000 /* (seconds) */ ], ... ]
  .map(([k, v]) => [ k, Date.now() - Date.parse(v) ])

// Run through that list, keeping track of the current value only if it
// is smaller than the previous value and positive.
  .reduce((pre, cur) => cur[1] < pre[1] && cur[1] > 0 ? cur : pre)

// ↑ returns [ key, value ], and we just want `key`.
[0];
```

If you want to compare against a specific time, replace `Date.now()` with `Date.parse()` and pass in a date string, like `Date.parse('Jul 07 2020 11:25:00')`.

Comment: thank you for your effort, unfortunately the result is still not as desired. I changed my time manually to 08 PM. As return value I get solarNoon (Mon Jul 06 2020 13:34:46 GMT+0200). In my times object I still have this entry: "evening": "Mon Jul 06 2020 19:06:36 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)". Normally the function should give me evening, because we are still in this phase...

Comment: @NiklasGrewe I have edited my answer. Please check if it is better now. I think this should be a much nicer and shorter solution than the currently accepted one.

Comment: it works now, a really cool and short solution, thanks again

Comment: I found one more little flaw... I manually set my time to 11:25. But I get ```solarNoon```, although solorNoon starts at Tue Jul 07 2020 13:34:55 GMT+0200. Actually it should give me ```morning```, because we are still in this phase. Could you maybe still fix that?

Comment: @NiklasGrewe That's because `morning` is four hours away from 11:25, whereas `solarNoon` is two hours away from 11:25 (See my updated answer for `solarNoon` comparison). You asked for the closest date, did you not? Or are you saying that you wish for the closest date that is not after the `compareTime`? That should be a simple change if that is the case.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite make myself clear. I meant the closest date that is not after the compareTime. Could you change that, please? That would be really nice...

Comment: @NiklasGrewe Please see the updated answer. I have rewritten it to be easier to follow as well. The actual change is as simple as removing `Math.abs` and checking for greater than zero in the `.reduce()`.

Comment: thanks for the revision, so with your time object it works, but not with mine. It still tells me that the current phase is solarNoon, although we are still in the phase Morning. Please take a look at this screenshot: https://ibb.co/MVHXwTQ - Do you have an idea why the filtering doesn't work for me? I can't explain it...

Comment: I think I found a mistake. I think he can't handle the 24-hour format. For example: If it's ```1:29 AM```, i get ```nauticalDusk``` but if it's ```1:30 AM```, i get ```solarNoon```. Would you know how to solve this?

Comment: I'm afraid not. They're being compared by their unix time, in seconds, so it's just a number. Any issue like this likey comes from how you're generating the dates in your `times` object. Perhaps you could ask a separate question about your generation not working as expected? You could go into more detail there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the dates in your times object.

Currently, JavaScript is just seeing them as strings so you're comparing a string to a number which returns false.

Try using `Date.parse(object[key])`. This returns a number.

Comment: thanks, this is my updated function: ```Object.keys(object).find(key => Date.parse(object[key]) < value);``` - it is right? because i never get the right key back.

Comment: You also need to convert the current date into a similar number.
`const now = new Date()`


`getKeyByValue(times, now.getTime())`

Comment: thanks, ok I did, I also get a key back, but not the one closest to the current time... How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to date objects, get the smallest delta, iterate em.

```
var times = {
   "dawn": "Mon Jul 06 2020 01:34:46 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)",
   "dusk": "Mon Jul 06 2020 22:43:02 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)",
   "evening": "Mon Jul 06 2020 19:06:36 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)",
   "morning": "Mon Jul 06 2020 08:02:55 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)"
};

var closestKey = null;
var closestDelta = null;

for(key in times)
{
  var delta = Math.abs(Date.now() - Date.parse(times[key]));
  
  if(delta < closestDelta || closestDelta == null)
  {
    closestKey = key;
    closestDelta = delta;
  }
}

console.log("The closest is:" + closestKey);
```

Comment: thanks for your time, but i can't test your function. I get "ReferenceError: key is not defined" on chrome console

Comment: Maybe you have it in strict mode. put var before key in the   for loop.

Comment: cool it works now, thanks for your time and for your quick help, you made my day

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out

```js
times = {
   "dawn": "Mon Jul 06 2020 01:34:46 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)",
   "dusk": "Mon Jul 06 2020 22:43:02 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)",
   "evening": "Mon Jul 06 2020 19:06:36 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)",
   "morning": "Mon Jul 06 2020 08:02:55 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)"
};
let obj = {}
for (time in times){
    Object.assign(obj, {[time]:Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(times[time]).getTime())});
}
//console.log(obj)
function closestDate(obj){
let closestVal = Math.min(...Object.values(obj))
    for (item in obj){
        if(obj[item] === closestVal){
            return item;
        }
    }
}
console.log(closestDate(obj));
```